# I am having a column like this 9(05),X(05),X(15). I want to separate this 9,X,X into one column and data in () into another column. How can I do that?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am having a column like this 9(05),X(05),X(15). I want to separate this 9,X,X into one column and data in () into another column. How can I do that? 
input column is 
9(05)
x(05)
x(15)
x(15)
s9(07)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pat = r'(.*?)\((.*?)\)'
df[['a','b']] = df['col'].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
print (df)
      col   a   b
0   9(05)   9  05
1   x(05)   x  05
2   x(15)   x  15
3   x(15)   x  15
4  s9(07)  s9  07
```

Comment: can someone explain me this pat = r'(.*?)\((.*?)\)'

Comment: @Sai Srinivas Rachapalli Sure, please check [this](https://regex101.com/r/ARMY8x/1)

Comment: Great link, didnt know it!